# Cannot read property 'Msgtext' of undefined while execution using protractor

Tags: protractor

I have created a function in my PO file as below,

```
'use strict';

var FunLib = function(){

this.Msgtext = element(by.css('.layout-row.flex-gt-md-66.flex'));
this.AltEle = element(by.css('[ng-show="alert"]'));
this.ExcMsg1 = "YOU ARE LACKING ONE OR MORE..."

//Function Button Click
this.ButtonClick = function(ButtonName){
    this.ButtonName = ButtonName;
    this.Button = element(by.buttonText(ButtonName));
    this.Button.click();
};

//Function to handle exception of Permissions
this.PermissionExc = function() {
    this.AltEle.isDisplayed().then(function(IsPresent){
        console.log(IsPresent);
        if (IsPresent) {
            this.Msgtext.getText().then(function(text) {
                console.log(text);
                var Message = text;
                if (Message == this.ExcMsg1) {
                    this.ButtonClick('Close');
                }
            });

        }
    });
    browser.sleep(2000);
}
};
module.exports = FunLib;
```

In my spec file I used it as below,

```
FuncLib.PermissionExc();
```

When I execute my code I am getting error "**TypeError: Cannot read property 'Msgtext' of undefined**".
Can anybody tell me where am I going wrong? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a famous js closure problem. You cannot access this.Msgtext inside a nested function. Because the scope of **this** you used does not have Msgtext

```
this.PermissionExc = function() {
  var _this = this;
this.AltEle.isDisplayed().then(function(IsPresent){
    console.log(IsPresent);
    if (IsPresent) {
        _this.Msgtext.getText().then(function(text) {
            console.log(text);
            var Message = text;
            if (Message == this.ExcMsg1) {
                this.ButtonClick('Close');
            }
        });

    }
});
browser.sleep(2000);
}
```

Same applies for others too